# What stops someone from DDOSing the 21 block producers?

Tags: block-producer, bp, ddos

From my understanding the top 21 block producers have very beefy systems and it would be very hard to ddos them. Is this true? What protections do they have from a ddos happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most block producer list and describe the hardware they use on their website:

https://eosauthority.com/producers_rank

They also often have multiple server in different location, for example a block producer located in Beijing China can have other server in Pekin or even another continent like Spain, and also I suppose they use the standard anti ddos protection https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDoS_mitigation